# python - read row and write it to file if it contains a specific value in a column

Tags: python, csv

I am reading a csv and I want to write to another output csv only the rows that have a specific value in a column.

This is my code:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

with open('contribs_01.csv', 'r') as file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file)

    with open('01_output.csv', 'w') as new_file:
        select_fields = ['contributorPersentTypeCd', 'contributorNameLast', 'contributorNameFirst', 'contributorStreetCity', 'contributorStreetStateCd', 'contributorStreetPostalCode', 'contributorOccupation', 'contributorEmployer', 'filerName', 'contributionAmount']

        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(new_file, fieldnames=select_fields, extrasaction='ignore')

        csv_writer.writeheader()

        for line in csv_reader:
            if pd.np.where(csv_writer.contributorPersentTypeCd.str.contains('INDIVIDUAL'):
                csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

This is the error I get:

```
  File "01_donor_read.py", line 17
    if pd.np.where(csv_writer.contributorPersentTypeCd.str.contains('INDIVIDUAL'):
                                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: pd.np.where(csv_writer.contributorPersentTypeCd.str.contains('INDIVIDUAL')):
you are not closing pd.np.where() function?

Comment: Voting to close as Typo

Comment: I'm getting this error when I fix the parenthesis.  Apparently I am misunderstanding the use of the module.  I thought I was supposed to put the column name where it's throwing the error.

`AttributeError: 'DictWriter' object has no attribute 'contributorPersentTypeCd'`

Comment: It would help if you [edit] the question to include a sample few lines (in text format) of your CSV file and show what output you are hoping to get.